# Execute a command as current user from local system service

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, windows-services

I have a Windows service that runs as Local System. I'm trying to invoke a PowerShell command (Get-AppxPackage), but it returns null under Local System. Is it possible to run this command as the Current User even though my service is running on Local System?

Is the only way to do this to call CreateProcessAsUser()?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered reconfiguring the service so that it runs in a real user's account?

Comment: `invoke a PowerShell command` - so this and create process, you really need exec PS by `CreateProcessAsUser` with user token. or you can done some task in process, by impersonate your thread with user token

Comment: "*run this command as the Current User*" -> which current user?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060822-00/?p=30013